# Getting compile error on ContentResolver.Insert() for creating event using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am now trying to create a Calendar event for Android platform. I am using Xamarin Forms but writing platform specific code for creating event on Android.

I went through the docs http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/calendar/

but I am getting the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property ... " for the following line.

```
ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look on below line and try it.

```
var uri = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

ContentResolver is a property of Activity, so you need an activity to call that method.

```cs
var eventValues = new ContentValues();
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "TITLE");                    
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, "LOCATION");
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "DESCRIPTION");
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, Java.Util.TimeZone.Default.ID);
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, startTime);
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, endTime);
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, isDayLong);
var uri = _activity.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
var id = uri.LastPathSegment;
```

You cann see, that ContentResolver property called on `Activity` object.